# C++ static const array initialization in template class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static, initialization

I have the following template class:

```
template <unsigned N>
class XArray {
  static const int Xdata[N];
};
```

I want to initialize the static const array for each `XArray<N>` I used, for example, let `XArray<N>::Xdata = {1, 2, 3, ..., N}`. How to make it?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705673/lazy-initialization-of-a-static-member-array-of-a-template-class) should help

Comment: It seems that ``array`` is a nice solution, thanks

Answer (score 4):

you declared a static const int array in your class,so you must define the static member out of the class declaration,just like this:

```
template<unsigned N>
class XArray
{
public:
static const int array[N];
};
template<unsigned N>
const int XArray<N>::array[N] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

But something you must pay attention to is that: when you use this template you must make sure that the "N" bigger than the number of your initialized array;

Comment: But can we use a constexpr function to init the static array with the full sequence of number from 1 to N..,?

Comment: I don't think so.Because when you declare a const member you must give it an initialized value,if you want to initialize every element of a const static array,you must use const_cast to change the const element to normal.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

It seems someone have already provided the solution for your problem in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981617/1550934), and the answer is quite the same as mine.

Also, for more generic answer, you can check out answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188092/static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c).

---

**Code**

If you don't mind using C++11 features, then [variadic templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/) may come handy:

```
template <unsigned ...Args>
struct XArrayData
{
    static const int Values[sizeof...(Args)];
};

template<unsigned N, unsigned ...Args>
struct _XArrayGenerator
{
    typedef typename _XArrayGenerator<N - 1, N, Args...>::Xdata Xdata;
};

template<unsigned ...Args>
struct _XArrayGenerator<1, Args...>
{
    typedef typename XArrayData<1, Args...> Xdata;
};

template<unsigned N>
struct XArray
{
    typedef typename _XArrayGenerator<N>::Xdata Xdata;
};

template <unsigned ...Args>
const int XArrayData<Args...>::Values[sizeof...(Args)] = { Args... };
```

**Explanation**

`XArray` template struct takes the number of array elements as a template parameter (`N`). In the compilation time, it uses `_XArrayGenerator` to generate template paremeter list with N consecutive numbers. It begins with the number `N`, and then recursively uses itself until it reaches 1. At this point, the template parameter list looks like this:

`1, 2, ..., N`

The last thing to do is to pass these parameters to `XArrayData`. The last line of the code (definition of the actual array) uses the parameters to initialize the array.

**Usage**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cout << XArray<3>::Xdata::Values[i] << endl;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize as shown below. See inline comments for my explanation.

```
template <unsigned N>
class XArray {
    private:
        static const int Xdata[N];
    public:
        //I added this for illustration purpose
        void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                std::cout << Xdata[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

//you can initialize like this
//automatic size counting works with static arrays
//here I initialize with 3 elements
//make sure you don't use N < 3 anywhere
template <unsigned N>
const int XArray<N>::Xdata[] = {1,2,3};

int main(void)
{
    XArray<3> obj1; //N = 3: This is okay.
    XArray<8> obj2; //N > 3: This is okay. Remaining elements will be 0.
    XArray<2> obj3; //N < 3: This is also okay.
    obj1.print();
    obj2.print();
    obj3.print(); //but this will give compilation error

    return 0;
}
```